# ReactiveCocoa: subscribe on property getter access

Tags: ios, objective-c, reactive-cocoa

Can I subscribe to be notified when a property getter is called, using ReactiveCocoa?

I need to set a flag that certain data needs to be updated (via network request) in the near future, because someone accessed it.

Comment: @JoshCaswell I've updated the question based on a reply to my answer. Though I questioned why the OP would want to do it this way, the question itself was clear enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know why you'd want to do this, I'd really suggest posting a question that asks what the best way to solve the problem you're seeking to solve. But, yes it's theoretically possible to do what you're asking, using `-rac_signalForSelector:`.

```
[[object rac_signalForSelector:@selector(property)] subscribeNext:^(id value) {
    // Getter has been called
}];
```

Comment: I need to set flag, that some data needS to be updated(by network request) in near future, because someone accessed it. You answer seems to be right. Thanks!